# Sourcebranch value is $/

Tags: .net, azure-devops

We are using the DevOps 2019 build server and some of the build definitions are returning a sourcebranch value like this $/ with the missing solution path.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sourcebranch value is $/

That because you are map two team projects in the Get Sources as in below image:

[image]

In this case, when you get the `sourcebranch`, Azure Devops could not find the their common parent folder, so it return the `$/`:

[image]

This issue has been reported to the MS team, but still no solution at this time:

Ticket: [Build.SourceBranch/Build.SourceBranchName returns empty](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/392991/buildsourcebranchbuildsourcebranchname-returns-emp.html)

Hope this helps.